# Code Coverage for Class is 0%

Tags: apex

Here is my Apex class:

```
Public class AutoConvertLeads
{
    @InvocableMethod  
    public static void LeadAssign(List<Id> LeadIds)

    {
        LeadStatus CLeadStatus= [Select Id,MasterLabel FROM LeadStatus WHERE IsConverted=true Limit 1];

        List<Database.LeadConvert> MassLeadconvert = new

     List<Database.LeadConvert>();
         for(id currentlead: LeadIds){
         Database.LeadConvert Leadconvert = new

     Database.LeadConvert();
         Leadconvert.setLeadId(currentlead);

     Leadconvert.setConvertedStatus(CLeadStatus.MasterLabel);
     MassLeadConvert.add(Leadconvert);
     }
     if (!MassLeadconvert.isEmpty()) {
         List<Database.LeadConvertResult> lcr =
         Database.convertLead(MassLeadconvert);
         }
       }
      }
```

Here is the test class:

```
@IsTest (SeeAllData=true) private class AutoConvertLead2_Test{

    /* This is a basic test which simulates the primary positive case for the 
       Conversion method of a Lead. */

private static testMethod void myUnitTest() {

// create a Lead
Lead lead=new Lead(LastName='Doe',FirstName='John',Company='Test',Status='Qualified for Contact');

insert lead;                

Database.LeadConvert lc = new database.LeadConvert();
lc.setLeadId(lead.id);
lc.setDoNotCreateOpportunity(false);
lc.setConvertedStatus('Converted');

Database.LeadConvertResult lcr = Database.convertLead(lc);
System.assert(lcr.isSuccess());
}}
```

On running the test class, it executes successfully but code coverage is coming out to be zero %.

Please assist what I am missing here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't actually *call* your class; you simply performed a direct lead conversion. Instead, try to convert the lead through your class:

```
@IsTest class AutoConvertLead2_Test{
    @isTest static void myUnitTest() {

        // create a Lead
        Lead lead=new Lead(LastName='Doe',FirstName='John',Company='Test',Status='Qualified for Contact');

        insert lead;
        // Try to convert lead using the class
        AutoConvertLeads.LeadAssign(new Id[] { lead.Id });
        // Verify lead was converted
        lead = [SELECT IsConverted FROM Lead];
        System.assert(lead.IsConverted, 'Expected lead conversion');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to spend some time at Trailhead and learn basics of [testing apex code](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/module/apex_testing)

Test class ensure that future updates you make to your app don’t break existing functionality

You will have to invoke your static method here and assert the final results

```
@IsTest (SeeAllData=true) 

 private class AutoConvertLead2_Test{

/* This is a basic test which simulates the primary positive case for the 
   Conversion method of a Lead. */

   private static testMethod void myUnitTest() {

   // create a Lead
   Lead lead=new Lead(LastName='Doe',FirstName='John',Company='Test',Status='Qualified for Contact');
   insert lead;                
   Test.startTest();
     list<lead> lstleads = new list<lead>();
     lstleads.add(lead);
     AutoConvertLeads. LeadAssign(lstleads);
   Test.stopTest();

    System.assertEquals([Select IsConverted from lead limit 1]. IsConverted,true);
   }

}
```